# What are rules governing Internal`RationalNoReduce?

Tags: internals

Consider the following example:

```
ClearAll[n1,d1,n2,d2,n3,d3];
{n1,d1,n2,d2,n3,d3}={20,6,20,12,5,1};
FractionBox[n1,d1]*FractionBox[n2,d2]+FractionBox[n3,d3]//DisplayForm
Internal`RationalNoReduce[n1,d1]*Internal`RationalNoReduce[n2,d2]+Internal`RationalNoReduce[n3,d3]
Rational[n1,d1]*Rational[n2,d2]+Rational[n3,d3]
```

This produces the correct output. `` Internal`RationalNoReduce `` produces 760/72 and `Rational` produces 95/9.

Now if I change the values to

```
{n1,d1,n2,d2,n3,d3}={20,6,30,12,5,1};
```

Now both `` Internal`RationalNoReduce `` and `Rational` produce 40/3 while 960/72 was expected for `` Internal`RationalNoReduce ``.

But now if I change the values to

```
{n1,d1,n2,d2,n3,d3}={20,6,20,12,5,2};
```

I get 290/36 for `` Internal`RationalNoReduce `` instead of the expected 580/72. `Rational` correctly fully reduces to 145/18.

So how exactly is `` Internal`RationalNoReduce `` working? What are the rules governing its behavior? I can't really rely on it for complex expressions involving fractions until I understand it or there is a way to fix it maybe.

Comment: Does `Trace` tell you anything?

Comment: Why expect 580/72 in the last one? I would expect 1160/144 through standard cross multiplying. Another example: ```Internal`RationalNoReduce[8, 4] + Internal`RationalNoReduce[6, 2]``` you would expect (8*2 + 4*6) / (4*2) or 40/8 but Mathematica returns 10/2 .

Comment: Response to update: Try `Trace`. You ought to investigate the pieces of your calculation before placing blame on any particular one.

Comment: @flinty When adding fractions we scale them up until their `Denominator`s each reach the `LCM` not the `Product` of the `Denominator`s. Which is happening correctly if you consider the case `{n1,d1,n2,d2,n3,d3}={20,6,20,12,5,3};`.